# Saving component library preferences in KiCAD

Tags: kicad

I have a local component library that I use in most designs. I've been adding this to the library list in Eschema for each new design because I can't figure out how to add this permanently via preferences or something. Is creating a template the right/only way to make this permanent, or is there a better solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries are populated by the default template, so you would need to adjust that to have additional libraries added by default.

Personally, I find Chris Pavlina's solution to be the cleanest:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpavlina/kicad-schlib/master/create_project.sh

This creates a new directory with a shallow copy of footprints and libraries and maps the config files appropriately.  I use a fork of this to maintain my own libraries and push back to GitHub any changes, so my next project inherits the updates.

Comment: editing the kicad.pro file turned out to be very easy, once I knew that's where to set the preferences. It appears that one could set up a project with the libraries and preferences one wants, save the project, then copy and rename the .pro file as the default kicad.pro file. The file location on windows is C:\Program Files\KiCad\share\kicad\template